# Using SSH in gitlab job to restart docker-container

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

I am trying to add some continuous deployment for a typescript API built with node, and mongodb.

I would like to do so via the gitlab instance that I already have :

Runner config (/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml) :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "runner"
  url = "https://git.[DOMAIN].[EXT]"
  token = "[ID]"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "mhart/alpine-node:6.5"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

So my deploy job looks as follow :

```
Deployment_preprod:
  stage: Deploy
  before_script:
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk add --no-cache --virtual openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - scp -r dist  user@[IP]:/home/[user]/preprod-back
    - ssh -tt user@[IP] cd /home/[user]/preprod-back && yarn run doc && docker-compose restart
  environment:
    name: preprod
    url: https://preprod.api.[DOMAIN].[EXT]
  only:
    - develop
```

**Question :** 
this job fail on `/bin/sh: eval: line 91: docker-compose: not found` which suprise me since running docker-compose [whatever] just works fine server-side when I log in the server via ssh.

Comment: `ssh ... && docker-compose ...` makes an outbound ssh connection and waits for it to finish; then after it’s done it tries to run `docker-compose` locally.

Comment: Would using a bash script solves this issue ? I guess not but sooner or later I will have to rebuild the image in order to have the nodes_modules up to date, so running docker/docker-compose commands on the server-side would seems very  usefull for me. I might have started on a wrong process though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` are tripping you up. You should quote the entire remote command.

```
script:
  - scp -r dist  user@[IP]:/home/[user]/preprod-back
  - ssh -tt user@[IP] "cd /home/[user]/preprod-back && yarn run doc && docker-compose restart"
```